# Integração de flair com linkedin

Tags: novo-recurso

Existe algum jeito de integrar as flairs do stackoverflow com o Linkedin? O único jeito que encontrei foi inserir o .png da flair sem o link.

Comment: Em todos os tópicos que encontrei, o link para a imagem do *flair* parece ser o único modo possível.

Comment: Tem algo que nós poderíamos fazer ou é algo que o Linkedin deveria fazer?