# Como incorporar flair do SO no linkedin

Tags: suporte

Já ando ando há algumas horas a tentar para evitar perguntar, mas não consegui.

Pelo que percebi a unica maneira de incluir o flair (url de maneira a que fique dinâmico, não a imagem só) do SO no linkedin é fazendo uma apresentação google (soponho que seja com https://docs.google.com/presentation), pois bem, o que fiz foi criar um diapositivo (slide) vazio, apenas com esta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto às opções de partilha coloquei como podem ver na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde creio ser aquele link que está *highlighted* que seja para partilhar no linkedin.

Ou seja, já no linkedin supostamente seria: `Add Media: presentation` na secção em que gostaria que aparecesse. Tudo bem, foi o que fiz, mas ficou o thumbnail vazio (sem imagem) apenas com o titulo em baixo, e quando clico para ver mesmo a apresentação aparece o diapositivo sem a imagem, apenas com o titulo e descrição, e um botão ("*read more*") que me leva para o link dos docs do google onde crio a apresentação.

Vejo que existem utilizadores desta comunidade que conseguiram fazer isso, gostava muito que alguém que soubesse me desse algumas diretrizes sobre como fazer.

Já pesquisei bastante mas nenhum dos caminhos foi bem sucedido, estes são apenas alguns links onde procurei a solução:

[How can I insert my Stack Overflow rating into LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121355/how-can-i-insert-my-stack-overflow-rating-into-linkedin)

[Integração de flair com linkedin](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2361/integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-flair-com-linkedin)

[Is it possible to show the Stack Exchange flair on LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22716/is-it-possible-to-show-the-stack-exchange-flair-on-linkedin)

[Add StackExchange profile to LinkedIn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270245/add-stackexchange-profile-to-linkedin)

Comment: Eu nem lembro como incluí a minha. Fica feio, mas deu certo, foi bem simples: https://www.linkedin.com/in/maniero/

Comment: Pois :P , não quis dizer diretamente na pergunta mas em si e no Utliuz que pensei quando escrevi "Vejo que existem utilizadores desta comunidade que conseguiram fazer isso...". Mas obgado na mesma @bigown, espero que alguém saiba e me esclareça

Comment: Você conseguiu incorporar o flair? Tentei aqui e só fica uma imagem padrão para documentos

Comment: @Sorack, não consegui apenas deixei assim: https://www.linkedin.com/in/miguel-fraz%C3%A3o-01974274?trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile_pic ... É pena, gostava de incorporar o flair, se souberes como fazer responde aqui se faz favor

Comment: Beleza, eu vou continuar tentando e se achar a solução eu posto como resposta

Comment: @Sorack, combinado obrigado

Comment: @Miguel és tuga? Não fazia ideia.

Comment: Hehe Portugal @JorgeB. Campeão da Europa aqui presente, Cascais aqui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partir da versão mais nova do LinkedIn, ativa hoje, é possível colocar o flair do SO. Ele é atualizado automaticamente a cada intervalo de 10 dias ao que parece. Coloquei o meu faz uns dias a atualizou sozinho hoje.
Você só precisa editar o seu perfil e na parte de `Mídia` clicar em `Link para mídia`. Lá você coloca o link da imagem.

**Localização do botão `EDITAR`:**

[image: Localização do botão EDITAR]

**Localização da área de mídia:**

[image: Localização da área de mídia]

**Pegando o link da imagem do flair:**

[image: Pegando o link da imagem do flair]

**Adicionando o link:**

[image: Adicionando o link]

**Aplicando:**

[image: Aplicando]

Comment: Não encontro a tal parte escrito "Mídia" depois de clicar em editar perfil. Na área Experiencia tem um link chamado Foto. Eu tentei adicionar um "Resumo" e depois cliquei em Foto, mas a imagem não carrega.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento adicionei as imagens de como eu fiz na resposta, dá uma olhada ali

Comment: Seu linkedin está bem diferente do meu, talvez só alguns tenham acesso :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o meu atualizou faz umas duas semanas, então pode ser que estejam liberando em lotes... Uma coisa que eu notei é que em casa, que não tem proxy, o meu flair já está atualizado, e aqui ainda está com 6.6k